# integrating 2 web.. embed one to another one

Tags: javascript, frontend

This is stereotype case that developer always says :  just use `iframe`, 
But I want another approach to resolve css & js conflict between of integrating website.

So, I'm event organizer that provide client with registration form.
I have front end apps to use by the client via embed script to their site.

I use jQuery and it always conflict the js & CDs to the client website. My boss uses angular and he always says that he never got the conflict css & js.

My current method is :

> - Ask the client to use pre-requisite 'static' js & css that my front-end apps use, which I hosted via the internet using jQuery.
> - My static host js will work with handlebarjs to load dynamic html.

For future plan i want it to load by `jquery.getScript()`

And my boss keeps telling me to built it like google analytics so that the client just need to attach 1 line script and it works like a charm.

is it possible .. ?

I'm asking and ready to hear the best approach without iframe.. thx in advanced

Comment: if you grabbed the HTML from one site and injected it into your own you'd be vulnerable to all sorts of badness which is mostly swept under the rug when you use an iframe or - better - some sort of semantic API where you get the actual data you want and choose how to render that yourself.

Comment: How about CORS whitelist ?

Comment: @moopet, How about CORS White list?